# Selecting a thumbnail from among a large, medium, and small image

Tags: c#, null

I'm parsing some data in C# where I have an object with 3 properties: "large", "medium", "small"; each property may contain a string array with an image path, and I'm trying to extract that path.

The data should always have a large image, but not always a medium or small. I'm trying to generate thumbnail images, so I prefer the small, but if it's not there I want the medium, otherwise the large. The following code works and I understand it but I have the feeling there's a more expressive way:

```
var thumb = (images == null)
            ? null
            : (images.small == null) || (images.small.Length == 0)
                ? (images.medium == null) || (images.medium.Length == 0)
                    ? (images.large == null) || (images.large.Length == 0)
                        ? null
                        : images.large[0]
                    : images.medium[0]
                : images.small[0];
```

I could at least break out the guard clauses to a Boolean method like `hasImage("small")` or better yet `hasImage(imageEnum.SMALL)` -- that would make the tests easier to understand and also encapsulate them so changes to the test logic wouldn't pollute the retrieval logic.

Other than that, is there a better (i.e. easier to understand) way to express the overall algorithm?

Comment: It seems to me that your class shouldn't be initializing any property if there is no data to populate it.  Also using multiple nested inline conditionals doesn't really gain you anything, use proper `if` blocks that return directly, eliminating any else blocks.  This is much easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: @tinstaafl The class is auto-populated -- I'm parsing JSON data, maping a JON object to an Images class, so the images object with all 3 properties -- s,m,l - gets created whether there's data to put into it or not. Later, the code above tries to retrieve the best image. As for if blocks, feel free to post an example but I didn't see any benefit -- just as easy or hard to read but ore verbose. I'm very much against hard-to-understand nested ternaries, but in this case they seem pretty straightforward and not any harder than ifs. I'm looking for alternatives to either syntax for ifs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think about the code that uses `System.Linq` extension methods?

```
public void ConsumingCode()
{
    var images = new Images();
    var thumbnail = GetThumbnailFrom(images);
    // ... rest of the code
}

private string GetThumbnailFrom(Images images)
{
    if (images == null)
        return null;

    var imageSource = new[] { images.small, images.medium, images.large }
        .FirstOrDefault(source => source != null && source.Length > 0);

    return imageSource?.First();
}
```

---

This may be a bit more compressed at the cost of readability, which I provide as an option rather than recommendation:

```
return new[] { images.small, images.medium, images.large }
    .FirstOrDefault(source => source != null && source.Length > 0)
    ?.First();
```

---

One more note. If whoever constructs the Images class can guarantee that `small`, and `medium`, and `large` are always set to at least empty arrays rather than `null`, we could throw away the ugly null check in the predicate.

And this

```
.FirstOrDefault(source => source != null && source.Length > 0)
```

would become this

```
.FirstOrDefault(source => source.Length > 0)
```

---

**P.S.**
Not sure, what is the exact structure of the object from which you retrieve data. The assumption is that it looks somewhat similar to this:

```
public sealed class Images
{
    public string[] small;
    public string[] medium;
    public string[] large;
}
```

Comment: Yes, your assumption about the `Images` class is correct. Thanks for the variations -- this is substantially like @t3chb0t 's answer, but without having to create a GetEnumerator, and I think it expresses the logic a bit more clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> var thumb = (images == null)
>             ? null
>             : (images.small == null) || (images.small.Length == 0)
>                 ? (images.medium == null) || (images.medium.Length == 0)
>                     ? (images.large == null) || (images.large.Length == 0)
>                         ? null
>                         : images.large[0]
>                     : images.medium[0]
>                 : images.small[0];
> ```
>
> I understand it but

no one else does ;-)

Ternary operators are very usefull but you really exaggerated. In a production code I would never accept it.

You should break it to smaller pieces.

> is there a better (i.e. easier to understand) way to express the overall algorithm?

There might be. If the `images` type is under your control then you could implement the `IEnumerable` interface on it and return the sub-image collections:

```
class ImageCollection : IEnumerable<Bitmap[]>
{
    public Bitmap[] small { get; set; }
    public Bitmap[] medium { get; set; }
    public Bitmap[] large { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<Bitmap[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return small;
        yield return medium;
        yield return large;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then with a small helper lambda you can encapsulate the first-image-or-default logic and use linq to retrieve the first image found:

```
var images = new ImageCollection();
var getFirstImageOrDefault = new Func<Bitmap[], Bitmap>(
    bitmaps => bitmaps == null ? null : bitmaps.FirstOrDefault());
var thumb = images.Select(getFirstImageOrDefault).FirstOrDefault(bitmap => bitmap != null);
```

Comment: Well, they're string arrays, not Bitmap arrays, but yes, this is pretty nice. The order of image-size resolution is the order of the `yield` statements in `GetEnumerator()`, correct? So if I wanted to favor large over small I'd reverse the order of the `yield` statements?

Comment: @Val exactly, the items are returned in the same order you write the `yield`s.